# Android Watch Face Setting Up

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os, android-2.2-froyo, android-sdk-tools

[The code I'm using](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-WatchFace/blob/master/Wearable/src/main/java/com/example/android/wearable/watchface/AnalogWatchFaceService.java)

Hi! I am using the code above for making my own watch face; and for line 127 it tells me that:
it cannot define the symbol "bg"!

My question: Why am I getting this error? Btw don't know if it's relevant but **I'm doing this within the default hello world app**

**and I'm also using a package companyname.test instead of the watch face one in that code...**

Everything else looks clean as far as syntax errors go....

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Watch face samples contains a number of [resources](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-WatchFace/tree/master/Wearable/src/main/res), one of which is a background graphic: [bg.png](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-WatchFace/blob/master/Wearable/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/bg.png). If you haven't included that resource in your project then you are attempting to reference a non-existent resource and receive an error.

Comment: How would I import this resource?

Comment: Copy it (or better yet, the entire `res` folder) into your project.

Comment: Sorry do you know where I can find a project with a watch face that was made already?

Comment: In Android Studio, go to the File Menu, Import Sample, select Watch Face